# mediaelemnt.js not working on Windows Server 2008 desktop

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have looked at my pages using Windows Server 2008 and ie9 but the player does not work, any ideas why this is .

I have been told that html5 audio and video does not work on Windows Server 2008 desktop and ie but should fall back to the flash version

Comment: Having same problem - *.mp4 just won't grab - tried most of the popular codec packs also tried with videojs and raw javascript - still haven't found a solution.